# Are electronics safe for babies

Tags: toddler, safety, screen-time, tablet-computer

My daughter is 3 years old and adopted. I've had her for 2 years now. When I got her she was crying non stop, now she will talk and laugh with everyone she meets.

I bought my little girl the newest iPad air 6 months ago to help her learn abc's and numbers and to entertain her when I'm busy, but it's gotten to the point where she can't go to sleep without her tablet, and she will be watching it even when I fall asleep then she's grumpy in the morning, if I take it she wont stop screaming.

Are tablets good for a child's brain? Are they harmful? I have heard of the radiation theory about brain damage from mobile phones but I do not know how accurate it is. I am concerned that the tablet may emit radiation that will harm my child's brain.

My question is twofold: Is the tablet good/bad for her developing brain and how can I take it from her without her screaming?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. This is a Q&A site (not a forum for discussion, with which you might be more familiar.) As such, questions must be clear. If your question is, "are electronics safe for preschoolers", the body of your question invites a lot of opinion (you need not say why you're asking unless it's pertinent), and you need to specify what you mean by 'safe'. If you want to know how to wean her off her Ipad (which is implied), that's a different question. Please edit your post, and again, welcome. We're here to help (if we can.) :)

Comment: I'll update my question

Comment: Your title says "Are electronics safe for kids?" but then you specifically ask about "radiation". Are you wondering if they are safe in general, or ONLY if the "radiation" has any merit? I ask because I think there are several other reasons why they would not be considered "safe" for young children.

Oh, the current age of your kiddo would probably be helpful too.

Comment: Am i wrong when i say this, when you wrap some copper around a piece of iron and hook it up to the negative post on a battery terminal, electrons come splurging out right, it's not until you give those electrons something positive to look forward to, that they start

Comment: moving to complete the circuit... so the batteries in ipads that give off electromagnetic radiation not to mention the radiation from the router and near by routers or cell phones, so yeah are electronics bad for kids in general or ??? They being the news says that microwaves, ipads, small radiation fields aren't harmful but cellphones are still extensively being studied, how can they say microwaves are safe and cell phones are not when i tested my microwave and it gives off more radiation that the cell phone or router i have... So an ipad falls under the electronic category for

Comment: electromagnetic radiation right.. https://www.google.com/search?q=radiation+from+the+router&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOkdXW_qHaAhUs5IMKHT1TDM0Q_AUICigB#imgrc=LEUgBN_H-1Yp0M:

Comment: To be honest you would have heard something by now, kids have been growing up with phones and tables for 10 years now, unless it has long long term problems (like alzheimer) we would already know about it, up to now there is no real science to back anything up.
I would be more worried about your baby/toddlers mental state. being bored and being creative what to do might be things she wont learn with her tablet everywhere (google being bored and you'll find lotes of stuff)

Comment: @hellomoto what you are talking about is a simple wire carrying current. This is not specific to phones, microwaves or tablets. By your definition, every single device that uses electricity to run emits "radiation" (and to be fair, even light is considered a form of "radiation"). I think normally "microwave radiation" is the concern from microwaves and something about cell signals is the concern from phones. You may find more specific information about the radiation thing by asking on the Skeptics SE. I'll take a crack at editing your question, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: @hellomoto See https://www.cancer.gov/about-cancer/causes-prevention/risk/radiation/cell-phones-fact-sheet. TL;DR if there is a risk its a very small one. Note that this is about cell phones not tablets. Cellphones use much stronger signals and users keep them held against their heads. A tablet only needs to talk to a router in the next room, and you use it at arms length, so the dose from a tablet is much MUCH smaller than from a phone.

Comment: @hellomoto In any kind of electrical circuit, whether its the power in your home or an iPad, the electrons stay in the circuit. The "electromagnetic radiation" happens when those electrons move around the circuit: they cause a kind of ripple. Imagine splashing your hands in a pond; your hands stay attached to your wrists but the ripples spread out across the pond. Something floating on the other side of the pond will move when the ripples hit it. Radio (including cellphones and WiFi) works in the same way; an aerial is a thing to send out ripples or to detect ripples made by something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screen time before bed is a very bad idea.  It will impair sleep, for adults and children.  There are a ton of resources about this online, here is just one:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5390665/

I would want to see a lot of good research before believing that a screen is effective at teaching a preschooler anything.

If you need to use a tablet during the day for a breather, fine, but stop doing it at night, and I wouldn't be telling myself that I was doing a world of educational good by using one, because that likely is not true, no matter what the people selling the software want you to think.

I don't know what you mean by "radiation theory".

Comment: If you have no idea what the OP means about 'radiation theory", then you're conclusion is a guess.  Also, I think this answer is unnecessarily hostile in tone, but it may be just the way I'm reading it, if so, apologies.  Maybe just adding support for your statements will soften it considerably.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I've editted the answer to remove the unhelpful last statement, which might make your comment unnecessary now?